# Conditional aggregation efficiency

Tags: sql, h2, conditional-aggregation

Let us have two tables.

```
A(id int primary key, groupby int, fkb int, search int, padding varchar(1000))
B(id int primary key, groupby int, search int)
```

They are created using the following scripts. The first table is large (1M rows) and the second one smaller (10k rows).

```
CREATE  TABLE A(
  id int not null primary key, 
  groupby int null, 
  fkb int null, 
  search int null,
  padding varchar(1000) null
)  AS
WITH x AS
(
  SELECT 0 n FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 3 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 4 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 5 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 6 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 7 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 8 FROM dual
  union all
  SELECT 9 FROM dual
), t1 AS
(
  SELECT ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n + 10000 * tenthousands.n + 100000 * hundredthousands.n as id
  FROM x ones,     x tens,      x hundreds,       x thousands,       x tenthousands,       x hundredthousands
), t2 AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            mod(id, 100) groupby
    FROM t1
)
SELECT  cast(id as int) id,
        cast(groupby as int) groupby,
        cast(mod(orderby, 9173) as int) fkb,
        cast(mod(id, 911) as int) search
FROM t2;

CREATE  TABLE B(
  id int not null primary key, 
  groupby int null, 
  search int null
) AS
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 0 n FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 3 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 4 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 5 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 6 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 7 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 8 FROM dual
  union all 
  SELECT 9 FROM dual  
), t1 AS
(
  SELECT ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n as id  
  FROM x ones,     x tens,      x hundreds,       x thousands       
)
SELECT  cast(id as int) id,
        cast(mod(id + floor(100000 / (id+1)) , 100) as int) groupby,
        cast(mod(id, 901) as int) search,
        rpad(concat('Value ', id), 1000, '*') as padding
FROM t1;
```

I would like to process the following conditional aggregation query in H2 as fast as possible, however, not adding any other index.

```
SELECT  B.groupby,
       count(CASE WHEN A.search = 1 THEN 1 END) as search1,
       count(CASE WHEN A.search = 900 THEN 1 END) as search2
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON A.fkb = B.id
WHERE B.search < 10
GROUP BY B.groupby
```

Is it possible to rewrite the query that the query runs at maximum 2 minutes? I have tried many different rewritings, however, each keeps running for minutes without end. I set the Java virtual machine memory to 4GB (-Xmx4G).

If I try the same test in MySQL and the query is processed in less then 10s.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization scripts have syntax errors, I modified them in the following way:

```
CREATE  TABLE A(
  id int not null primary key, 
  groupby int null, 
  fkb int null, 
  search int null,
  padding varchar(1000) null
)  AS
SELECT  cast(x as int) id,
        cast(mod(x, 100) as int) groupby,
        cast(mod(mod(x, 100), 9173) as int) fkb,
        cast(mod(x, 911) as int) search,
        rpad(concat('Value ', x), 1000, '*') as padding
FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(0, 999999);

CREATE  TABLE B(
  id int not null primary key, 
  groupby int null, 
  search int null
) AS
SELECT  cast(x as int) id,
        cast(mod(x + floor(100000 / (x+1)), 100) as int) groupby,
        cast(mod(x, 901) as int) search
FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(0, 9999);
```

I also used H2-specific `SYSTEM_RANGE()` for simplicity.

The EXPLAIN command with you query shows the following execution plan

```
SELECT
    "B"."GROUPBY",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ("A"."SEARCH" = 1) THEN 1 END) AS "SEARCH1",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ("A"."SEARCH" = 900) THEN 1 END) AS "SEARCH2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."B"
    /* PUBLIC.B.tableScan */
    /* WHERE B.SEARCH < 10
    */
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUBLIC"."A"
    /* PUBLIC.A.tableScan */
    ON "A"."FKB" = "B"."ID"
WHERE "B"."SEARCH" < 10
GROUP BY "B"."GROUPBY"
```

This is expected, because you don't have any indexes. Unfortunately, you can't improve performance significantly without them.

I think you need a constraint here.

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT A_FKB_FK FOREIGN KEY(FKB) REFERENCES B(ID);
```

With such constraint execution plan is much better:

```
SELECT
    "B"."GROUPBY",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ("A"."SEARCH" = 1) THEN 1 END) AS "SEARCH1",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ("A"."SEARCH" = 900) THEN 1 END) AS "SEARCH2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."B"
    /* PUBLIC.B.tableScan */
    /* WHERE B.SEARCH < 10
    */
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUBLIC"."A"
    /* PUBLIC.A_FKB_FK_INDEX_4: FKB = B.ID */
    ON "A"."FKB" = "B"."ID"
WHERE "B"."SEARCH" < 10
GROUP BY "B"."GROUPBY"
```

With constraint your query needs about 11s on my old PC.

You can also use the `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE A.search = 1)` in your query with H2, but such query will not be compatible with MySQL, MySQL doesn't support the standard SQL:2003 FILTER clause yet and FILTER clause doesn't really improve performance of this query, it only provides better readability.